# Throwing errors in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my package, before I perform a query on my database I check if some of the params provided are valid:

```
//check
if(!$this->checkId($id)) //error

//do the query
$user = User::find($id);
```

What's the best way to handle this in a laravel package?

Throw an error? If so, which kind? Do an app abort?

Answer (score 1):

### Using findOrFail()

There is a pretty good method that Laravel provides just for this case called `findOrFail()`.

What you can do is use that and then catch the exception.

```
try {
    $user = User::findOrFail($queryParam);
} catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    // Do things that should happen here if your query parameter does not exist.
}
```

If you do not wish to catch it here, you can setup a listener for this exception.  You can place it anywhere you wish as long as it's being autoloaded.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Response::make('Not Found', 404);
});
```

### Throwing an exception

If all you want to do is throw an error if a query param isn't available, you can throw any of the exceptions found here... https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception

If none suit you, you can create your own and just extend `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` and `throw new YourCustomException($statusCode, $message);`.  Just follow what they've done in the other exception classes and it should be fairly easy.

Then you can modify the the "exception listener" to catch `YourCustomException`.

Here is a tutorial I found... http://fideloper.com/laravel4-error-handling

Comment: It might also be worth looking into [`Model::findOrNew()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e60ea917ab862254a6db37fa9cb8933138c1e73c/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L647-L659).

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer the question, I need to know how to throw an error, if you re-read the question you'll see that I do not need to use find or fail or throw an error on a query, but just on a standard method.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question because you are asking "What's the best way to handle this in a laravel package?" and I gave you what I thought was the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Event Listeners for the most control.

Create an `events.php` in your `app` directory and include it in `app/start/global.php`
Or, you can register anywhere in your package.

Create a listener:

```
Event::listen('paramCheck.noId', function($id)
{

    // do some logic, log something, return something, throw an error...

});
```

Then fire the event from whenever you need to:

```
if(!$this->checkId($id))
    $returnFromEvent = Event::fire('paramCheck.noId', array($id));
```